# Extracting a data from json array by certain key in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I have a json array which im getting my react data from it,
the json is like this:

```
 {
         "Folders": [
           {
             "name": "parent 2",
             "children": [        //this is children_1
                {
                  "name": "parent 2",
                  "id": "parent 2",
                  "children": []     //this is children_2
                 }
               ],
               "id": 1
            }
          ]
        }
```

lets say i have the key value of name inside children(children_1) and i want to get the rest of the data inside that children using the name that i have, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: I tried to edit it so its fully understandable, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath)

so it will be

```js
var json = require('jsonpath');
var names = jp.query(json, '$.Folders[*].children[*].children');
```

Comment: cant really get it to work

Comment: what is your data you are referring to ? Did I understand correct that you need get all from deepest children list ?

Comment: i have the value "name" inside (children_1), and i want to get the rest of the values inside (children_1), using that name.(something like finding the name with its value and then getting the parent).

Comment: something like this `jp.query(json, '$.Folders[*].children[?(@.name === "parent 2")].children')` ?
please read npm documentation